# "Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0-4-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory" when running update-initramfs

Tags: apt, kernel

I have a standard Ubuntu 12.04 (32bit PAE) installed. At one time I used xorg-edgers PPA (I wanted to see how far nouveau has gotten) which also provided a linux kernel 3.5.0.4.

Since edge xorg made my system unstable I used ppa-purge to downgrade packages to stable which also uninstalled kernel 3.5.0.4, but the removal process didn't remove 3.5 images in /boot, which has caused warnings during package operations when a package would trigger `update-initramfs`:

```
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0-4-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
```

Deleting 3.5 images in /boot made the warnings go away, but after today's update they are back again. None of the 3.5 deb packages are installed but somehow my system remembers that it had a 3.5 kernel at one time. I'm wondering where this info is stored and how can I remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sudo update-initramfs -d -k 3.5.0-4-generic`.

It looks like the initramfs did not get removed for some reason when the kernel did.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the file /var/lib/dpkg/status and edit as appropriate, but first make a backup of the file so you can roll back if needed.

Comment: Nope, the file doesn't contain '3.5.0.4' or '3.5.0-4'. Also package managers like synaptic or aptitude don't have 3.5.0-4 listed either as available, installed, or anything.

Comment: Is the fact that the system has an unused(?) 3.5 kernel causing you any issues as such? If not, why not just leave it as is?